# Read process, output wait for a specific output and exit immediately

Tags: c#, process

I have `.bat` file that start `appium` server (`appium` command line) and i am do this via `.bat` file:

```
var process = new Process();
var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/C c:\tools\start_appium_aerver.bat");
startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo = startinfo;
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Data); // do whatever processing you need to do in this handler
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

When `appium` starts, I want to know if the server starts successfully by read the `process` output and wait for the specific line:

```
appium server start listening
```

At this point when I found this line and know that my server is ruining instead of use this command and wait for several seconds:

```
// Wait until appium server starts 
process.WaitForExit(30000);
```

I want to be able to exit immediately (using `process.WaitForExit` without any value is a bad idea because the server runs all the time)

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, when the `OutputDataReceived` event is raised, read the value and, if it's what you're expecting, exit the process. Otherwise, you'll exit when the timeout you have set has elapsed.

Comment: I'm unclear - do you want *your* process to exit immediately or do you want the *started* process to exit immediately?

Comment: The appium server continue to run of course but i want my method (the code i posted) to exite and then i will know that the server is running

Comment: Instead of wait until WaitForExit endsa

Answer (score 0):

Have your `OutputDataReceived` handler call [`Environment.Exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=netframework-4.7.2) once it's seen the required text to tell it that your server has started.

You still may want to have the code block that created the `Process` use `WaitForExit` (with or without a timeout) if its the only active foreground thread in your application, just to stop you exiting too early (the event handler on `OutputDataReceived` isn't enough, so far as I'm aware, to keep your process running if no foreground threads remain in the process)

Comment: So i can still use WaitForExit and just call Environment.Exit when i know that my appium server is running ?